# Laravel 5.7 Many To Many Relation Problem With Pagination

Tags: laravel, model, relation

i have some problem with this relation in laravel.
[this is my mysql tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0dgM.png)

and this is my controller code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dynamic;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Blogs;
use LaravelLocalization;
use App\BlogsCategory;


class BlogsController extends Controller
{
    public function main(){
        //$posts = new Blogs::where('lang',LaravelLocalization::getCurrent);
        $posts = new Blogs;
        $data = $posts::where('lang',LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale())->where('created_at','<=',NOW())->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(config('PAGINATOR_COUNTER'));
        return view('Dynamics.Blogs.Main',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

and this is my Blogs Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\BlogsCategory;

class Blogs extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(BlogsCategory::class);
    }
}
```

and BlogsCategory Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Blogs;

class BlogsCategory extends Model
{
    public function blogs_data()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Blogs::class);
    }
}
```

i want to get all blogs posts that their lang col is 'fa' with their category and show in my view.
this is my view code:

```
@forelse($data as $tmp)
                        <div class="blog-item-left">
                            <div class="blog-left-img">
                                <img src="/upload/blogs/small/{{$tmp->img}}" alt="{{$tmp->title}}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog-left-text">

                                <div class="blog-text">
                                    <span><i class="fas fa-box"></i>
                                    @foreach($data->categories as $cat_data)
                                        {{$cat_data->title}}
                                    @endforeach
                                    </span>

                                    <a href="#"><h4 class="title">{{$tmp->title}}</h4></a>
                                    <p>{{$tmp->description}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>




                        @empty
                        <h2>No Data to show!</h2>
                    @endforelse
```

and this code show me this error :

Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$categories (View: /Users/soroush/Sites/msadd/resources/views/Dynamics/Blogs/Main.blade.php)

what i must to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to load the "categories" relation with your query.

```
class BlogsController extends Controller
{
    public function main(){
        //$posts = new Blogs::where('lang',LaravelLocalization::getCurrent);
            $data = Blogs::with('categories')
                ->where('lang',LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale())
                ->where('created_at','<=', now())
                ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
                ->paginate(config('PAGINATOR_COUNTER'));

                return view('Dynamics.Blogs.Main',compact('data'));
            }
}
```

And change your blade(view) template "categories" iteration like this:

```
@foreach($tmp->categories as $cat_data)
    {{$cat_data->title}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but now this code show me this error, i think my views code have some problem too :
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$categories (View: /Users/soroush/Sites/msadd/resources/views/Dynamics/Blogs/Main.blade.php)

Comment: The first problem at your query. You can change your query with this. Another problem at your view template I see at the moment. So I am changing my reply.